# A* move to excact position, if close, otherwise approach

Tags: unity, c#, path-finding, rts

I'm using the A* project from http://arongranberg.com/ and have this annoying problem, that I'm incapable of solving.

When walking to a destination, I want my units to just get close to the waypoints in order to have less calculations and let the path look more natural. But with the current method, they also only approach their destination, which makes formations etc. look awful.

I tried to check if the distance to the target is smaller than the approaching distance `(nextWaypointDistance = 1.0f)` but this resulted in the unit stuttering. Here's the full Method, that's called every Update:

```
public void moveAction()
    {
        if (path == null) // kein Pfad        
            return;        

        if (currentWaypoint >= path.vectorPath.Count) // Ende des Pfades
        {
            moving = false;
            return;
        }

        Vector3 dir = path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint]; // Richtvektor für nächsten Wegpunkt

        if (can_move) // Bewege zum nächsten Wegpunkt
        {
            if (rotating) TurnToTarget();
            else if (moving) MakeMove(dir);
        }

        if (currentWaypoint < path.vectorPath.Count)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint]) < nextWaypointDistance)
            {
                currentWaypoint++;
                return;
            }
        }             
    }
```

I removed my workarounds from the code, hoping that some of you can provide a better idea.

I somehow believe that this is an obvious thing I missed

---

**EDIT:**

As requested, the MakeMove function:

```
   private void MakeMove(Vector3 dir)
    {
        inCover = false;
        transform.LookAt(dir);
        float scaledSpeed = 1 / moveSpeed;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, dir, scaledSpeed);
        if (transform.position == destination) moving = false;
        CalculateBounds();
    }
```

Example: I want my units to go from a single line to a double line.
Using a hardcoded `transform.position = position[unit]` will created the wanted result as seen here:
[image]

but using the A* movement this would be the result:
[image]

And I have absolutely no clue, why. If I'd keep spamming the formation hotkey, it eventually will create a proper line after about 20 clicks

Another example with only one unit would be this:

[image]

As you see, the cursor and marker is at the desired spot, but the unit is far away. (using the same movement method)

Comment: I'm guessing the most important parts of your code are actually related to your "MakeMove" function which you haven't shown here.

Comment: @DannyYaroslavski Ah, sorry, forgot this^^ But as I check if the postion == destination, I thougth this one is okay

Comment: Have you considered having your *formation* follow the waypoints, and then units seek toward their assigned position relative to the formation?

Comment: @DMGregory would lead to the same problem, that the unit doesnt exactly move to the desired position. Happens also with only one unit, But yes, this would be the next step.

Comment: It sounds like it would be worth editing your question to add more details (or visual examples) of units failing to move the the desired position. The specific symptoms of the problem can reveal a lot about what's going wrong.

Comment: @DMGregory added Images

Comment: @DMGregory It seems like the MakeMove method is responsible for this, indeed. Changing the lerp to just the position creates perfect movement. But I have no clue, why this is wrong

Comment: If you've solved the problem, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: @DMGregory Haven't solved it yet, no clue whats wrong with lerp in this case

Comment: @TechTreeDev You are using Lerp incorrectly.  Please see [Using `Vector3.Lerp()` correctly in Unity](http://www.blueraja.com/blog/404/how-to-use-unity-3ds-linear-interpolation-vector3-lerp-correctly)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft If I'd use moveTowards it's the same problem, though, but thanks for mentioning